# SAS create 10 new variables according to 10 existing one with a do loop

Tags: loops, if-statement, sas

I have a PAR file, with 10 variables: q1-q10 which has values in range of 0-1.
I need to create for each variable (q1,q2,q3...) a new variable that will receive values of 1-5 according to the following range
 0< q <0.2 => 1

0.2< q < 0.4 => 2
and so on..

eventually for each q should be a new column should be an additional column with values from 1-5

I have managed to create it for one variable, but how can I do it for all 10 of them in a more efficient way?

```
 data PAR1; set PAR;
if q1>0 and q1<0.2 then do; qq1=1;end;
if q1>0.2 and q1<0.4 then do; qq1 =2;end;
if q1>0.4 and q1<0.6 then do; qq1=3;end;
if q1>0.6 and q1<0.8 then do; qq1=4;end;
if q1>0.8 and q1<1 then do; qq1=5;end;
run;
proc print data=PAR1;
run;
```

Comment: Are you sure that your data does not have any values on the borders? Right now, you'll probably get a missing value if the value is interpreted as 0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array.

```matlab
data par1;
    set par;

    array q{*} q1-q10;
    array qq{10};

    do i = 1 to dim(q);
        if 0 < q[i] < 0.2 then qq[i] = 1;
        else if 0.2 < q[i] < 0.4 then qq[i] = 2;
        else if 0.4 < q[i] < 0.6 then qq[i] = 3;
        else if 0.6 < q[i] < 0.8 then qq[i] = 4;
        else if 0.8 < q[i] < 1 then qq[i] = 5;
    end;

    drop i;
run;
```

The first `array` statement creates an array consisting of all 10 `q` variables. The second initializes 10 new `qq` variables, which will be named sequentially `qq1` through `qq10`.

This loops over all variables by their *index*, i.e. position, in the array. So `q[2]` references `q2` and so on. For each variable, the new variable is assigned based on the logic you provided.

As an aside, note that you have inequalities in your logic but not equalities--this will result in missing values when, for example, `q1 = 0.2`.